# How to find the path to the REST service in ASP.NET MVC SPA

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm playing with ASP.NET MVC SPA with Knockout, and I've noticed that the sample code generated by Visual studio hard-codes the URL for the API in the javascript code as "/api/...". Obviously this only works if the application is rooted at '/' on the web server. I would have thought there might be something built into the framework to handle this but I can't find it.

At the moment I've just put the following in my _Layout.cshtml to create a global javascript variable:

```
var ApplicationPath = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath';
```

But it seems a bit kludgy and breaks the separation of concerns given that this is supposed to be a state-of-the-art design paradigm. Is there a better way to do this?

I have always used relative URLs at the past (with web forms) but it seems to me this would be a bad idea in MVC because because you can get at the same page by /myApp, /myApp/Home or /myApp/Home/Index.

Comment: I would be very wary about equating "sample code generated by Visual Studio" and "state of the art design paradigm".  VS starter templates are designed to get you up and running fast, not show you the best way.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't saying that I expected the sample code itself to be state-of-the-art, but that the combination of technology I'm using supposedly should be